# how to attach downloadable file in virtuemart 2 in joomla

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, virtuemart

I am using virtuemart extension version 2.0.22a in my joomla site.

I want to sell digital products using vm(virtuemart). So when payment done user will be able to download product zip file.

But it seems i can't find where & how do I attach product download files in vm 2. Earlier versions of vm had downloads tab in configuration.

It's look like i have to buy another paid plugin for this said here - 
[help forum topic](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=111890.0)

This should not be accepted, there should be way to attach downloadable files(zip,..) with the product at least.Even many free e-commerce sites, extensions have at least downloadable files. So why should not be here in vm.

Any one help me to attach downloadable zip file with the product in vm or if its that i need to add a paid plugin then tell me alternatives.

Comment: Hi joomla virtuemart experts?

Answer (score -1):

If you can customize the VM little bit an alternative option in my mind, I am not sure this is acceptable for you.

When someone place an order in your site an order confirmation should send as email that email should have a proper order_id and expiry token. Also a download count in your custom table.

And order confirmation page should says check your inbox.(or even you can set the link inside confirmation page).

Check the link and validate order id,expiry token and download count.

Also if the files are not large in size you can choose attach file option for email.

Hope its give some idea for your task.

Comment: hi you are little late in reply.I already got another way by posting in vm forum here [post link](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=117652.0) so how better is that than what you suggested?

Comment: I think the logic used in the plugin are same as above.So if you have enough time and better coding knowledge on VM so its simple task only one table need to create and choose for download link within the page.